# Retrieve data and display into multiple controls with loop , c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

net sql server , I want a loop to retrieve data from sql database to different label controls using C# asp.net sql server storedprocedure.

```
string constrng = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["baby"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constrng);
SqlCommand sqlComm;
sqlComm = new SqlCommand("stor_proc", conn);
sqlComm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
conn.Open();

SqlDataReader dr = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add("Home");
ds.Tables[0].Load(dr);

m.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
i.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
d.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
g.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();

m1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[1][1].ToString();
i1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[1][2].ToString();
d1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[1][3].ToString();
g1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[1][4].ToString();

m2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[2][1].ToString();
i2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[2][2].ToString();
d2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[2][3].ToString();
g2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[2][4].ToString();

conn.Close();
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: how i can apply loop in this

Comment: You can see that you need two loops, one for .Rows[x] and the second for .Rows[x][y]. But why all the text boxes, how about a grid of some sort?

Comment: @Chuck - actually there was a mistake , as labels name are m,i,d,g, m1, i1, d1 , g1, m2,i2,d2,g2 and so on,,,,

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
   m.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
   i.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
   d.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();
   g.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    // Now here, you are iterating through a individual row.
    // ItemArray gives an index position of a cell within a row.

    m.Text = row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
    i.Text = row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
    d.Text = row.ItemArray[2].ToString();
    g.Text = row.ItemArray[3].ToString();

}
```